# Hibernate doesn't save edited entities, while saves new ones

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, testng

I'm facing a weird problem. I'm currently writing a web application based on Spring-MVC 3.2, and Hibernate 4.1.9. I wrote a sample controller with its TestNG unit tests, and everything is fine except for editing. I can see that when saving a new object, it works like a charm, but if I try to edit an existing object, it doesn't get saved without giving out any reason (I'm calling the same method for adding and updating).

The log of adding a new object of type Application

```
14:26:36.636 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name '' processing POST request for [/app/add.json]
14:26:36.637 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /app/add.json
14:26:36.650 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.Long com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.apps.web.AppController.createApp(com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.model.apps.Application)]
14:26:36.651 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'appController'
14:26:36.821 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Reading [class com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.model.apps.Application] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@5dc6bb75]
14:26:36.890 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Opening Hibernate Session
14:26:36.890 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 13580799968
14:26:36.892 [main] DEBUG c.w.c.dao.hibernate.BaseDaoHibernate - Saving or Updating Object: com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.model.apps.Application@54fc519b[id=<null>,name=KinzHunt,company=com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.model.apps.Company@151c2b4[id=1,name=KinzHunt],callbackUrl=http://www.kinzhunt.com/callback/,website=http://www.kinzhunt.com,senderEmail=no-reply@kinzhunt.com,logoUrl=<null>]
14:26:36.892 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Opening Hibernate Session
14:26:36.893 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 13580799968
14:26:36.893 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Closing Hibernate Session
14:26:36.894 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - executing identity-insert immediately
14:26:36.898 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
14:26:36.899 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
14:26:36.899 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:platform_test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]
14:26:36.901 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - /* insert com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.model.apps.Application */ insert into applications (id, callback_url, company_id, logo_url, name, sender_email, website) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
14:26:36.904 [main] DEBUG o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 2
14:26:36.904 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
14:26:36.905 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Closing Hibernate Session
14:26:36.905 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
14:26:36.905 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
14:26:36.926 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Written [2] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@5dc6bb75]
14:26:36.927 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name '': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
14:26:36.928 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

While the log for saving an edited object is

```
14:27:03.398 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name '' processing POST request for [/app/1/edit.json]
14:27:03.398 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /app/1/edit.json
14:27:03.401 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.Long com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.apps.web.AppController.editApp(com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.model.apps.Application,java.lang.Long)]
14:27:03.401 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'appController'
14:27:03.404 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Reading [class com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.model.apps.Application] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@5dc6bb75]
14:27:03.409 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Opening Hibernate Session
14:27:03.410 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 13580800234
14:27:03.411 [main] DEBUG c.w.c.dao.hibernate.BaseDaoHibernate - Saving or Updating Object: com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.model.apps.Application@1ba4f8a6[id=1,name=KinzHunt,company=com.wstars.kinzhunt.platform.model.apps.Company@6bc06877[id=1,name=KinzHunt],callbackUrl=http://www.kinzhunt.com/callback/,website=http://www.wstars.com/KinzHunt/,senderEmail=no-reply@kinzhunt.com,logoUrl=<null>]
14:27:03.412 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Opening Hibernate Session
14:27:03.412 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 13580800234
14:27:03.413 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Closing Hibernate Session
14:27:03.422 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Closing Hibernate Session
14:27:03.424 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Written [1] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@5dc6bb75]
14:27:03.424 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name '': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
14:27:03.425 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

As you can see, in the second log, no prepared statement is created, and no JDBC connection is opened. My test configuration for the database is like this:

```xml
<bean id="targetDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:platform_test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="targetDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.mypackage.model.*</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="namingStrategy">
        <bean class="com.example.common.config.MyOwnNamingStrategy"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="1" />
            <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <!-- <property key="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/> -->
    <!-- <property key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory"/> -->
</bean>

<bean id="h2WebServer" class="org.h2.tools.Server"
    factory-method="createWebServer" depends-on="targetDataSource"
    init-method="start" lazy-init="false">
    <constructor-arg value="-web,-webPort,11111" />
</bean>
```

My controller code is:

```java
@Controller
public class AppController extends BaseAnnotatedController {

    @Autowired
    private AppManagementService appManagementService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/app/add", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody Long createApp(@RequestBody Application app) {
        saveApp(app);
        return app.getId();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/app/{appId}/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody Long editApp(@RequestBody Application app, @PathVariable Long appId) {
        if (!appId.equals(app.getId())) {
            WSError error = new WSError(ValidationErrorType.GENERIC, "id");
            throw new ValidationException(error);
        } else {
            saveApp(app);
            return app.getId();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/app/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Application> listApps() {
        return appManagementService.listAllApps();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/app/{appId}/get", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Application getAppDetails(@PathVariable Long appId) {
        return appManagementService.getApplication(appId);
    }

    private void saveApp(Application app) {
        if (isValid(app)) {
            appManagementService.saveApp(app);
        }
    }

    public @ResponseBody List<Application> listAllApps() {
        return appManagementService.listAllApps();
    }
}
```

My test class is:

```
@Test
public class AppControllerIntegrationTests extends AbstractContextControllerTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    AppController appController;

    @Autowired
    private AppManagementService appManagementService;

    @Autowired
    private BaseDao baseDao;

    @BeforeClass
    public void classSetup() {
        Company comp = new Company();
        comp.setName("Some Company");
        baseDao.saveObject(comp);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddInvalidAppWebJson() throws Exception {
        String appJson = getInvalidApp().toJsonString();
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/app/add.json")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(appJson);
        ResultActions resultAction = this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);
        resultAction.andExpect(status().isForbidden());
        MvcResult mvcResult = resultAction.andReturn();
        Exception resolvedException = mvcResult.getResolvedException();
        assertTrue(resolvedException instanceof ValidationException);
        ValidationException validationException = (ValidationException) resolvedException;
        assertEquals(validationException.getErrors().size(), 3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddAppWebJson() throws Exception {
        Application app = getMockApp();
        String appJson = app.toJsonString();
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/app/add.json")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(appJson);


        this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isOk());

    }

    @Test
    public void testEditAppWithWrongIdWebJson() throws Exception {
        String appJson = getMockAppWithId().toJsonString();
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/app/2/edit.json")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(appJson);
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden())
                .andExpect(
                        content()
                                .string("{\"errors\":[{\"errorType\":\"-100\",\"field\":\"id\",\"constraint\":null}],\"objects\":null}"));
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"testAddApp", "testAddAppWebJson"})
    public void testEditAppWebJson() throws Exception {
        Application app = getMockAppWithId();
        setAppWebsiteToDifferentOne(app);
        String appJson = app.toJsonString();

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/app/1/edit.json")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(appJson);

        this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEditInvalidAppWebJson() throws Exception {
        Application app = getMockAppWithId();
        app.setWebsite("Saba7o 3asal");
        String appJson = app.toJsonString();
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/app/1/edit.json")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(appJson);
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden())
                .andExpect(
                        content()
                                .string("{\"errors\":[{\"errorType\":\"-114\",\"field\":\"website\",\"constraint\":null}],\"objects\":null}"));
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods="testEditAppWebJson")
    public void testGetAppDetails() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/app/1/get.json");
        Application app = getMockAppWithId();
        setAppWebsiteToDifferentOne(app);

        this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(app.toJsonString()));
    }
}
```

My service method is:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public void saveApp(Application app) {
    baseDao.saveObject(app);
}
```

All test methods pass, except for the last one, since it's expecting the website of the app to be the one which was edited. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to know which hibernate method is called in saveApp() also make sure your service is annotated with @Transactional.

Comment: I annotated the service method, but still no difference. Also, I didn't have any transaction manager running, so by default, all transactions should be read/write transactions (especially that adding objects work fine)

Comment: You were right after all. I configured the transaction manager, and everything worked fine. I don't understand how addition to the database was working.

Comment: When you add @Transactional annotation and also configuring the transaction manager spring will perform a commit after the method is completed successfully otherwise rolback, may be insertion was succeeding because it didn't require a transaction, another thing, in case of update you don't need to call save or update explicitly, hibernate will commit your changes automatically provided you attached the object by loading it from DB first and then update the data of the loaded object, then all the updates to the loaded object  will be saved automatically.